# UserInfo missing in audio call

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am using `QuickBlox` version 2.8.0.1.

I am facing problem that `UserInfo` in `AudioCall` is missing for some reason. My case as below:
Step1: Make an audio call to some opponents, I also added a call information in `UserInfo` for example on iOS:

```
- (void)didReceiveNewSession:(QBRTCSession *)session userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
```

I could receive call however `UserInfo` is missing, It is not always happen but sometimes I got.

OTHER cases:

When I accept a coming call from 1 of opponents:

```
- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session acceptedByUser:(NSNumber *)userID userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
```

This method was never called, but I could receive delegate in case rejection:

```
- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session rejectedByUser:(NSNumber *)userID userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
```

Could you please help me on this?

BR,
William Tran

Comment: hello @Nobita kunz please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please check below step to get Userinfo in this

     let userInfo = ["name" : "\(User.sharedInstance.firstname) \(User.sharedInstance.lastname)"]

     self.currentSession?.startCall(userInfo)


    in didrecievce session method 

    func didReceiveNewSession(_ session: QBRTCSession, userInfo: [String : String]? = nil) {
}
```